# Ionic 2 : setInterval work only one time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I use Ionic 2 and I want to set an interval to increment a variable.

I tried this :

**home.ts**

```
public num : number = 0;

  constructor(...) {

    this.counter = setInterval(this.countNum(), 1000);

  }

  countNum() {
    console.log(this.num);
    this.num = this.num + 1;
  }

  displayCount() {
    alert(this.num);
  }
```

**home.html**

```
<button (click)="displayCount()">Afficher</button>
```

**Problem :** My method is called just one time and I don't understand why. 
If I write this :

```
this.counter = setInterval(function () {
      console.log("toto");
    }, 1000);
```

It's works but it's not what I want to do.

Any idea ?

Comment: try this `this.count = setInterval(this.countNum.bind(this), 1000);`

Comment: Well ! the bind works ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: you can also replace `function()` by `()`

Comment: The syntax of setInterval is as such `setInterval(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)`. If you would like to pass in multiple parameters you can do it like `setInterval(this.countNum, 1000, this, param2, ...);`